# Creating an UPDATE RETURNING query in Hibernate

Tags: java, database, oracle, hibernate

In Oracle we can create an update query that will return the updated record using the RETURNING clause.

Is there similar functionality in Hibernate?

Comment: Isn't the object after saving already updated?

Comment: Yes the object saving after the update is already updated.

Comment: I guess for our case it is more of a design approach. These requests are initiated via webservice calls, which then update the DB. We have decided to return any updated or created object back to the user with the appropriate HTTP status. Within our code we have chosen to track the update up and down the web stack.

Comment: Then you should just returned the updated instance along with the status code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from database-generated values there is obviously no need for Hibernate to return the updated instance because the object passed to `Session.saveOrUpdate()` *is* the updated instance. Database-generated values (sequence, trigger, defaults, etc.) will be set *after* `Session.saveOrUpdate` if they are accordingly annotated (or defined in a XML mapping file).

For [identifier values](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/manual/en-US/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id) use the JPA `@javax.persistence.GeneratedValue` annotation in conjunction with the JPA `@javax.persistence.Id` annotation. For [simple properties](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/manual/en-US/html/mapping.html#mapping-generated) use the native Hibernate `@org.hibernate.annotations.Generated` annotation (afaik there is no according JPA annotation).

How generated identifier values are retrieved by Hibernate depends on the generation strategy and/or the database dialect. For simple properties Hibernate executes an additional `SELECT` by id statement after the `INSERT` or `UPDATE`.