# Update and Return Updated column using returning keyword in same query in java jdbc code

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jdbc, spring-data-jpa

```
 update account set lastusedval=lastusedval+1 where isactive=1 returning 
 lastusedval;
```

How to execute above query in java?
when i tried to execute in oracle its working but in java hibernate/jpa no way to store return value in update query.

By executing above query intention is to apply lock on db level when more than 1 request comes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating an UPDATE RETURNING query in Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9672589/creating-an-update-returning-query-in-hibernate)

Comment: Also possibly of interest: [Execute native sql with hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24782717/2144390)

Answer (score 0):

Using jdbc prepared statement with registeroutparameter might help you to resolve this issue.

[Creating an UPDATE RETURNING query in Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9672589/creating-an-update-returning-query-in-hibernat)

Comment: Um, `registerOutParameter` (note spelling) is used with `CallableStatement`, not `PreparedStatement`. Good catch on the dup, though.